# Setattribute text parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a text element to my dynamically created SVG chart so that I can have labels generated but can't make it work.

There is a WHILE loop for adding boxes for a chart. I use the same while loop for text labels and it isn't working, it makes the boxes also fail. When I remove text labels, it works perfectly.

Your help much appreciated.

```
<svg id="mysvg" width="1000" height="800"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<text x="50" y="60" fill="black" 
   font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
   font-size="28">Revenue and Expenses</text>
<line x1="150" y1="80" x2="150" y2="320" 
   style="stroke:rgb(155, 144, 144);stroke-width:5" />
<script type="application/ecmascript"> 
  <![CDATA[
   var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

   var chartStart = [152, 84, 152]
   var chartWidth = [100,64,36]
   var chartNames = ["Revenue", "Expenses","Profit"]
   var chartColor = ["#28CE6D","#DF3456","#4DC7EC"]
   var num = chartNames.length;

   while (num-- > 0)
   {
    var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
        rect.setAttribute("x", chartStart[num]);
        rect.setAttribute("y", [num] * 70 + 100);
        rect.setAttribute("width", chartWidth[num]);
        rect.setAttribute("height", "50");
        rect.setAttribute("style", "fill:" + chartColor[num] + ";stroke:black;stroke-width:0;opacity:1");

    var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
        text.setAttribute("x", "280");
        text.setAttribute("y", [num] *70 + 130);
        text.setAttribute("style", "fill:black");
        text.setAttribute("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif");
        text.setAttribute("font-size","18");
        text.setAttribute("textContent", chartNames[num]);

   mysvg.appendChild(rect);
   mysvg.appendChild(text);
 } 
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Check the console, so you can find your typo here: `text.setAttribute("style", "fill":black");`

Comment: Thanks @Triby, that was definitely an issue but now I've corrected to text.setAttribute("style", "fill:black"); it still doesn't work

Comment: I insist, use the console to find the error, now in this line: `text.setAttribute("y" [num] *70 + 100);` setAttribute requires 2 params and you provide only 1.

Comment: Thanks again @Triby found that one :) now the chart works but still no text coming through

Comment: Hmmm, when I inspect one of the text elements, it shows as `<text x="280" y="130" style="fill:black" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" font-size="18" textContent="Revenue"></text>` so it doesn't know there is text stated with textContent. I'm stumped

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found my own solution, I had not created a text node to append to the value for text element. Fixed it using the below. I'm sharing so that this question doesn't go unanswered. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<svg id="mysvg" width="1000" height="800"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<text x="50" y="60" fill="black" 
   font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
   font-size="28">Revenue and Expenses</text>
<line x1="150" y1="80" x2="150" y2="320" 
   style="stroke:rgb(155, 144, 144);stroke-width:5" />

<script type="application/ecmascript"> 
  <![CDATA[
   var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

   var chartStart = [152, 84, 152]
   var chartWidth = [100,64,36]
   var chartNames = ["Revenue", "Expenses","Profit"]
   var chartColor = ["#28CE6D","#DF3456","#4DC7EC"]
   var num = chartNames.length;

   while (num-- > 0)
   {
    var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
        rect.setAttribute("x", chartStart[num]);
        rect.setAttribute("y", [num] * 70 + 100);
        rect.setAttribute("width", chartWidth[num]);
        rect.setAttribute("height", "50");
        rect.setAttribute("style", "fill:" + chartColor[num] + ";stroke:black;stroke-width:0;opacity:1");

   var label = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
       label.setAttribute("x", "280");
       label.setAttribute("y", [num] *70 + 130);
       label.setAttribute("style", "fill:black");
       label.setAttribute("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif");
       label.setAttribute("font-size","18");
   var txt = document.createTextNode(chartNames[num]);
       label.appendChild(txt);

   mysvg.appendChild(rect);
   mysvg.appendChild(label);
 } 
 ]]>
    </script>
   </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```